How to convert a number on the log2 scale to natural log
I need to convert a number in the log2 scale (4.6), to the natural scale.
Using Rmpfr in this example (text doesn't work as there is no way to input my data as base = (natural log). I cannot see any other packages that will allow me to do this. I wonder what it is I am missing. Apologies if this is a very simple question; I'm very new to quantitative research.

log(2^x) should work? Based on your link, you seem to be confusing bases for number systems (binary is 2 and you write numbers like 10110, decimal is 10 and you write numbers like 22, hexadecimal is 16 and you write numbers like 0x16) with bases for logarithms. They are not really related.

log(x, base2) = log(x, base1) / log(base2, base1) See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base

Thank you so much for your help. I see number systems and bases are different. For log(2^x), why does this work? I reviewed the change of base formula but I don't think it's what I need here as 4.6 is already on the log2 scale. The change of base formula does not help me know what 4.6 is on the natural log scale. Unless I'm missing something.

As pointed out in the comments, there are two ways to do this:
x1 <- log(2^4.6)

first converts the number back from log2 to the unlogged scale (the value is 24.25), then computes its natural logarithm (3.188).
The change-of-base formula uses more math, but is slightly more efficient (especially if you compute the value of log2(exp(1)) (or log(2)) once, store it, and re-use it in multiple calculations).
x2 <- 4.6/log2(exp(1))
## this can also be expressed as:
x3 <- 4.6*log(2)
stopifnot(all.equal(x1, x2))
stopifnot(all.equal(x1, x3))

